# Execute code at the end of each quarter of year

Tags: wp-cron

I need to execute a script once every time we reach the end of a quarter (30th of March, 30th of June, 30th of September and 31st of December.

I've found `wp_schedule_event` on the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) and I generated the following snippet

```
// Custom Cron Recurrences
function custom_cron_job_recurrence( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['quarterly'] = array(
        'display' => __( 'quarterly', 'textdomain' ),
        'interval' => 7884000,
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence' );

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( '' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'quarterly', '' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
```

I'm not sure though, that the clock will start counting from the 1st of January.

Which is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It won't do it on the dates you chose, but rather it'll do it on the first cron run after `7884000` seconds have passed, that's how WP Cron works. If that time comes and nobody visits your site for 3 days, then it'll take another 3 days on top for the cron job to trigger. Since what you're trying to do is very non-typical, can you explain some context? There is probably a much better/easier way to do what you need to do than using WP Cron like this

Comment: Also, you might want to test with a smaller time frame. Otherwise you're going to have to wait 3 months each time you need to test

Comment: I need to create a certain amount of posts every time a quarter finishes. I could also create a trigger that checks the timestamp and executes the script only if the quarter passed and if the script has not been executed for that quarter, but this would mean to run the timestamp check most of the time without success

Comment: hmmm would it not make more sense to ask about that rather than WP Cron?

Comment: The request is already generic, I presented my guessed solution (that I know has downsides), I asked if anyone knows a better option

Comment: Asking about your original problem, and noting a solution you devised as an addition, would provide a lot more context, making it much easier to find the better solutions ( of which there almost certainly are several ). By asking a specific but generic WP Cron question that's no longer possible, and you've limited the number of answers you could have gotten, as well as restricted yourself to this kind of solution. It may be that no new posts need to be created at all, or that no WP Cron is needed whatsoever, but without knowing what the posts are and why you're creating them, who knows

Answer (score 3):

You can specify when the first execution will be performed using the first parameter of the [`wp_schedule_event`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) function. So, according to your code, the first execution will be immediately and the following one will be in 7,884,000 seconds (which is around 91.25 days).

I do not recommend this approach because the WP cron scheduled periods accept only fixed-time periods, expressed in seconds. What I would do would be to schedule it daily, and check before performing your actions whether the current day is one of the four options: 3/30, 6/30, 9/30, or 12/31.

Something like:

```
function custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'custom_cron_job_run' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'daily', 'custom_cron_job_run' );
    }
}

function custom_cron_job_run() {
    if ( in_array( date( 'n/j' ), [ '3/30', '6/30', '9/30', '12/31' ], true ) ) {
         // Do your stuff.
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
add_action( 'custom_cron_job_run', 'custom_cron_job_run' );
```